# Adding custom collection to the eloquent within Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I have a query and I want to add a collection using Laravel query builder.

```
Hotel::addSelect([
   'selectableLocations' => AllLocations::orderBy('name')->get()
])
  ->with('location')
  ->get();
```

Well, this returns:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters (SQL: select `[{"id":1,"name":"John Avenue"},{"id":4,"name":"Ontirio Village"},{"id":2,"name":"Rovie"},{"id":3,"name":"Movie Lot"}]` from `dogs` limit 100 offset 0)

I know this may seem like an anti-pattern but the reason I need this is because I have a datatable and want to show a select (dropdown) with AllLocations so that user can change in the datatable.

My idea is that I can do `$dog->selectableLocations` to see all locations. Because if I don't do it like this, it will query for each row individually.

Is there a way to do that?

---

If I could achieve it like this, that'd be perfect.

```
$selectableLocations = AllLocations::get();

$hotels = Hotel::addSelect([
    'selectableLocations' => $selectableLocations
])
  ->with('location')
  ->get();
```

Comment: Because join will need matching properties `->join('locations', 'dogs.id', '=', 'locations.location_id')`, right? The arguments `'dogs.id', '=', 'locations.location_id` will match them to relationship. How can I use `join()` for it to return it all in that table?

Comment: ah sorry i deleted the comment realising it was a stupid question. should have left it as it is, just to be clear for future readers, I asked "why not use joins?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

> Because if I don't do it like this, it will query for each row individually.

Since your primary concern is multiple queries, you could avoid db calls if you implement some sort of caching. Why not include the list as a custom attribute, load collection from cache? Like so:

```
public function getAllLocationsAttribute()
{
    return Cache::remember('all_locations', 30, function(){ //add remove seconds as required
        return AllLocatiobs::get();
    });
}
```

---

How about getting merging the two collections?

```
$hotels = Hotel::get();
$selectableLocations = AllLocations::get();
$hotels->put('selectableLocations', $selectableLocations);
```

Now, `$hotels->selectableLocations` will be a collection of AllLocations.

Comment: You added collection into another collection. I need a way to add it in via query builder.

Comment: Oh I seem to have completely missed your question, and wasted your time. Apologies. However, I would like to suggest one more approach, but I dont this this is still not what you are looking for.. let me update the answer.

Comment: Sure, please update your answer. Also please check the update in the OP

Comment: updated. that's the limit of my capacity. sorry if I frustrated you with useless suggestions, but I do think the caching could work until a better option is found.

Comment: Haha, cache came to my mind too.. I guess I'll use that until another option is found. Thanks for your time!